# Including c files leads to undefined references

Tags: c

When I include c files, I start to get undefined references to other functions. Then, I have to start including the c files that contain the functions. How do I get around this? The undefined references are referenced in the c files that I include, but since I am not actually including those files, I get undefined references.

Comment: You know that you are not supposed to be including C files, only H files, right?

Comment: egidra did not say #including. Maybe it means including in the project.

Comment: This sentence does not make sense: "The undefined references are referenced in the c files that I include, but since I am not actually including those files, I get undefined references". In your sentence, the pronoun "those" can only possibly refer to the antecedent "the c files that I include", but then you claim "I am not actually including those files" which is a direct contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally one includes ".h" files, not ".c" files.

If you call a function declared in a .h file, it is not sufficient to compile the starting C file to get a complete program -- you also need to link in the object files associated with the code that implements the declared functions. These might be in a library, in which case you need to link with that library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either compile all the files at once (`gcc *.c`) or compile each `.c` file into a separate object file and then link them all into the executable:

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c helper.c -o helper.o
gcc -c other.c -o other.o
gcc *.o -o main
```

And within each `.c` file you should only ever include `.h` files.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by including? Including via the #include preprocessor directive, or including as in adding them to your project.

You cannot get around the fact that all of the functions that are called (or, generally, externals symbols that are referenced) in your program either have to be included in that program, or have to exist in a library that is linked to the program, explicitly or implicitly.

Just keep adding the source files that are needed until all the references are resolved.

If you can't do that, then you may have some problem with the program or build. Either the program is incomplete (missing source files), corrupt (missing parts of source files), or you have included an inappropriate source file into the build (e.g. a source file which is needed when the program is compiled for Unix, but you're building for Windows) or incorrectly configured (so it is conditionally compiling some code for the wrong platform) or the program is simply not ported to your system (makes references to library functions you don't have).